# Edit made to "Why Locrian #2" is inappropriate?

Tags: discussion

On the question [Why Locrian #2?](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36396), Matt L. posted this:

> It should actually Locrian ♮2 (natural 2), because there's no sharp involved. The reason why you find it as Locrian #2 is probably just because most people find it easier to produce a hash symbol on their computers.

This was edited by a different user to:

> It's also called the Locrian ♮2 (natural 2), because there's no sharp involved - just that the b2nd in Locrian becomes a ♮2.

And the reason given is:

> Comment: Removed the error regarding the term Locrian #2: This from Mark Levine's Jazz Theory Book on Modes of the Melodic Minor- The Half-Diminished Chord: The half diminished mode is often called the Locrian #2 Mode, because the only difference between it and the Locrian mode is the second note...

Is this edit appropriate? To me, it doesn't correct a grammatical mistake, or clarify a poorly-worded sentence. Rather it seems like a change to the content of Matt L.'s answer. From how I'm reading the comment made by the editor, the reason for the change is that Matt L.'s answer had an error. If folks disagree on the accuracy of a statement, isn't the correct response to downvote, not to edit the post?

Comment: You are **very late** to the discussion. I downvoted the post because of the error. There was some back and forth - objection to the downvote , etc. I edited the post to remove the error. The OP rolled it back. Finally I proved that it was indeed a blatant error, re-edited the post and removed the downvote and so it has remained. Why are you opening up this can of worms again, after nearly 2 months of "peace"

Comment: After the edit, I upvoted the post. Now I have to remove the upvote. IMO you should have left well enough alone - this was already a closed case.

Comment: Hi Stinkfoot - it does appear that your edit changed the whole first paragraph. If you think his post is wrong, you should just downvote it.

Comment: @DrMayhem -  I did exactly that, since my edit has now been rolled back, after the OP apparently accepted my edit originally once I cited reliable sources for the term Locrian #2. He had originally rolled it back but relented when I brought sources. As it stands now, that answer contains a blatant error and you should also down-vote it, as should anyone who cares about the quality of the material posted on the site.

Comment: @Stinkfoot, I read all comments and checked the edit history before making this change. I was looking for something specifically like that and didn't find it. Where is the back and forth you're referencing? Did I just miss it?

Comment: @Stinkfoot, and as a philosophical matter, convincing the OP to make the change on his/her own builds a stronger community in the long run. This happened to me once on a post. I had some information that wasn't quite right, and instead of editing, others pointed out obvious errors (I think you were one). I can't remember if I edited the post or deleted it altogether, but it was a much more pleasant experience because of the helpful feedback and reasons you provided.

Comment: @Stinkfoot I agree with Dr. Mayhem and jdjazz that a better way to address a problem with an answer is to comment about what you see is wrong with it and/or downvote. Generally a third-party edit that changes what the answer says is not ideal, even if it changes a wrong answer to a right one. Third party edits that fix grammar, clarify the language, and add additional notes are generally ok to excellent. An example of a wonderful kind of edit to make here is to add the American or British note value names when an answer has only one. For example, change "crotchet" to "crotchet (quarter note)".

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya this is what the meta is for. There is more discussion here for the reason of hashing out issues.